# How can I return the lowest value inputted without using an array

Tags: c++

Notice this is a homework problem I am not looking for the answer, but rather hints to help me solve my issue. The goal of the program is to list min and max numbers inputted without using an array. The input of 0 should be inputted to exit the program, but should not be recorded as the "low" value. I attempted to set low to not equal zero in the if statement, but it returns a 0 regardless.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter a Number: ";
    double input;
    int max = -100000000;
    int low = 100000000;
    cin>>input;
    for(int i = 0; i = input; i++){
    cout<<"Enter Another Number:";
    cin>>input;
    if(input > max != 0) { max = input; }
    else if (input < low != 0) { low = input; }
    }
    cout<<"MAX NUMBER WAS: "<< max << endl;
    cout<<"LOWEST NUMBER WAS: "<< low;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `if(input > max != 0)` is checking?

Comment: @GBlodgett I emailed my prof. and he said and I quote "set max to a small number means -10000000
input != 0 (and not low)  should be in the "if" part and do it also for the "if" part of max"

Comment: The first part (`input > max`) will resolve to a bool (int value either 0 or 1), so you will be comparing whether `input` is more than `max`, which probably isnt what you want

Comment: usually, max set to the first number you get.

Comment: Instead first check to see if `input` is zero (`if(input == 0)`) and act accordingly to it. Then check to see if `input > max`

Comment: Instead of using *magic* numbers (e.g. `-100000000, 100000000`) use the correct min and max for type, e.g. `int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`

Comment: Why not control your program with a `while ((cin >> input) && input != 0) { /* do your checks here */ }` loop? Further, you need only `if (input > max) max = input;` and `if (input < min) min = input;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I dont have points to give you comments for hints, here i will add hints:
So, the easiest way to get the right solution of any problem is to visualize it or write simple example on paper for example:
user inputs:

> 1,4,6,10,0

Think to your self how do you find the smallest and the largest number if someone shows you this numbers in the same order? what will you do?
So, at start when you seen the first number **1** for you is the smallest and the largest because you don't have more inputs right?

> min = 1 and max = 1

That someone who is showing you the numbers in the given order now shows you the second number **4** What you will do at this moment ? For sure you are going to compare the if the **input** is smaller than the **min**(or **1**) in your current stage, and if the **input** is smaller than the **min** you save the **input** value to the **min** or same thing for **max**: if the **input** is greater than **max** you save input value to the **max**(or in this case because our second number is **4** and the value of **input** is greater than **max**)so

> **max** will take **4** and **min** will be **1**

. You repeat same thing for all the inputed numbers, or you can make **while loop** if the **input** is **-1** the loop will end.
I think I give you the idea of what you need to do and help you with my hints. And sorry because I gave you the source code in my previous answer which I edited it now. :)

Comment: What is the reason you added a system call at the bottom, seems unnecessary for the situation. Also, the question clearly stated they did not want the solution, so perhaps it would be beneficial to edit your answer to be more "hint-like"?

Comment: Or at least wrap it in preprocessor conditionals so it is only executed on windows, e.g. `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64) system ("PAUSE"); #endif` (note: that is 3 separate lines)

Answer (score 0):

C++ offers this mechanism to find out machine specific min and max values, so you don't put values like 100000 to your variables:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

You could use them for your `min` and `max` variables. As an alternative, you could use the first number given and assign it to both `min` and `max`.

So, in the end,

```
int number = 0, min = 0, max = 0;
std::cin >> number;
min = max = number;
while (number != 0) {
    if (number < min)
        min = number;
    else if (number > max)
        max = number;
    std::cin >> number;
}
```

Something like this would be enough. Then, you could use the variables however you want. This way, you didn't have to use an array for storing all the variables. 
Also, I suggest you to have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you are a beginner.

Comment: Well -- you need to use the numeric limits. Currently if `min = -395;` and `max = -100;` you are kind of "up a creek"...

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a `while(1)` instead of `for(int i = 0; i = input; ++i)`. This will be an infinite loop. You can add a break statement to come out of the loop using if condition. With `i = input` condition loop may never execute.

2) Break condition in your case is when `input = 0`. So add an `if (input == 0) break;` statement in the loop.

3) Modify the matching conditions to

```
if(input > max) { max = input; }
if (input < low) { low = input; }
```

4) Read the new input after matching conditions.

```
while(1){
    if (input == 0) { break; }
    if(input > max) { max = input; }
    if (input < low) { low = input; }
    cout<<"Enter Another Number:";
    cin>>input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use while here rather than for loop that you have used. Try this :

```
    int n, max, min;
    std::cout << "Enter a No. : ";
    std::cin >> n;
    //Assign 1st input to max and min 
    max = min = n;
    while(1){
        std::cout << "Enter a No. :";
        std::cin >> n;
        if(0 == n) //Terminating condition for loop
            break;
        if(n > max)
            max = n;
        else if(n < mi)
            min = n;
    }
```